# How do I display an empty field form for an embedded relationship in Rails Forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a question that has many answers, and I want to display a blank input field for an answer:

```
- @q = Question.new
= form_for @q do |f|
  = f.label :title
  = f.text_field :title
  = f.label :answers
  = f.fields_for :answers, @q.answers do |fields|
    = fields.text_field :title
  = f.submit "Update"
```

But currently only my question title blank input is displaying, but no answers blank inputs???

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way (following conventions) to set up a form with nested field:

```
#controller
@question = Question.new

#view
= form_for @question do |f|
  = f.label :title
  = f.text_field :title
  = f.label :answers
  = f.fields_for @question.answers.new(title: 'default title') do |answer_fields|
    = answer_fields.text_field :title
  = f.submit "Update"
```